# How to check value of local variable in method using JMockit or by other mechanism

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

How to check value of local variable in method using JMockit or by other mechanism? For example

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    DatabaseOperations databaseOperations;
    public void someMethod()
    {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        databaseOperations = new DatabaseOperations();
        someClass.setValue1(2);
        someClass.setValue2("some String value 3");
        databaseOperations.addObjectToDatabase(someClass);//I have mocked the class DatabaseOperations.
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    int value1;
    String value2;
    public int getValue1()
    {
        return value1;
    }
    public void setValue1(int value1)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }
    public String getValue2()
    {
        return value2;
    }
    public void setValue2(String value2)
    {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }
}
```

How to check what values `someMethod()` has set for local instance `someClass`.

Comment: [JMockit: Capturing invocation arguments for verification](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#withCapture)

Comment: This is to check arguements of method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I thought, you want to mock `SomeClass`. If not, why not simply use the getters?

Comment: I am testing `someMethod()`, How to check values in instance `someClass`? I can not use getters in this case.

Comment: What is the purpose of the method `someMethod`? You are creating an instance and then you directly discard it. _What exactly are you trying to achieve?_

Comment: @Varun The other commenter is right; in a real test, the class being tested would either return the `someClass` object, or store it into some field, or pass it as argument into some other method call. In each of those cases, you would be able to get access to the object in order to perform assertions on its values.

Comment: @Rogério No. In my real code this is not happening. We are adding this object to database. I can get row from database and check values, But I have mocked the class which is adding objects to database, So the object is not really getting added to database.

Answer (score 0):

Does this snippet do the trick for you ?

```
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void classToTest_someMethod(@Mocked final SomeClass someClassMock) {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                new SomeClass();
                result = someClassMock;

                someClassMock.setValue1(2);
                someClassMock.setValue2("some String value 3");
            }
        };
        new ClassToTest().someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this snippet code is checking calls to methods `setValue1()` and `setValue2()`, but I want to get local variable of method like we can get instance variable by using method `getField()` of `mockit.Deencapsulation` class.

Comment: The snippet is checking calls to methods `setValue1()` and `setValue2()` (with correct arguments) but it also verifies that these methods are called **on** **the** **exact** **instance** of `SomeClass` that was created in `someMethod()` (what you are called _local_ _variable_ if i understand you right)